# C# scripts in Unity opening new instance of VS15 instead of adding to existing instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I recently had to reinstall Unity + Visual Studio. And previously both were working fine (I had installed VS15 + Unity separately - however this time I installed VS15 through the 'Unity Tools installation')

However since then, when I try to open a script from Unity, it opens a new instance of VS15 each time - the kicker is when it opens this new instance, it also opens the previously opened scripts too.

So for all intents and purposes it opens all the scripts I want in one particular instance.....however to do this it for some reason opens a brand new instance rather than simply adding to an existing one?

For example;

I open `Script_A` by double clicking it in Unity. 
 It Opens the first instance of Visual Studio 15 (as it should - this shall be referred to as "First Instance")

I then want to open up `Script_B` by double clicking it in Unity also. However rather than simply opening this script in the "First Instance". It will relaunch a new instance of VS15 (AKA "Second Instance"). Once the "Second Instance" has loaded it will have `Script_B` opened as well as `Script_A`. Whereas "First Instance" still only has `Script_A` open.

The same thing happens if I open up a third, forth etc script, it will launch a new instance each time, rather htan just adding to an already opened instance.

Is this an issue encountered when VS15 is installed through Unity launcher, or is it some other issue (preferences, settings, either with Unity or Vs15 itself?) as it is quite annoying.

Comment: FYI that phrase is:  *"for all intents and purposes"*.

Comment: shhhhh I'm tired hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Open C# Project` by right clicking on Project Window instead of opening just one by one script. VS opens csharpsolution that way. Open scripts from project explorer in VS.

[image]

Had the issue. Fixed that way. Not using VS tool for Unity.

Comment: Yes but its a lot easier for me to just double click a broken script that has been highlighted for me in the Unity Inspector, rather than having to go and search for it through the project explorer in VS....I've always been able to use Unity, its only now that I have this issue where it opens an ew instance each time :'(

Comment: If you open as c# project for first time, you may not end up opening new instance next time opening a new script. Fixed in my case as i mentioned. Not using the tool though.

Comment: This has fixed it for me too. Thanks....bit of a pain but hey ho it works haha :)